# Neo4j match by range performance

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I've got following setup:

About 1,5m nodes of type `IpRangeBlock` consisting of `start` and `end` properties - both of them are of type Long. There's an index on the `start` property.

What I then do is to find a range containing given IP. So, e.g. for ip `0.0.0.2` I convert it to long and then perform comparison on all nodes `n.start <= 2 && n.end >= 2`.

The cypher query I run looks like this:

```
MATCH (n:IpRangeBlock) WHERE n.start <= {ip} AND n.end >= {ip} RETURN n LIMIT 1
```

All is fine, though as I mentioned, for 1,5m nodes I have it can take up to 20s for Neo4j to find matching range. My question is, is there a way to speed up this operation or is the fault in my db design?

Comment: Which version are you using? Index for range queries has been added in 2.3 I think.

Comment: Specifically if you use the normal exact index for the property then range queries will use it.  Though that might just be for the form `value < n.prop < value`.  Maybe not `n.prop1 < value < n.prop2`.  But definitely make sure you have an index and then `PROFILE` your query to see if it's hitting the index.

Comment: 2.3.1 - when I run `PROFILE` on the query in question I see that it calls `NodeIndexSeekByRange` in the first phase of execution plan.

Comment: Are there many properties on your `IpRangeBlock` nodes?  How many are returned?  It might be spending time returning the data

Comment: Nope, it only has `start` and `end` + something like 5 relationships each. I always run it with the LIMIT option so, if i'm correct, it should lazily only grab one node. Should I create index on both properties? It's only set on the `start` one.

Comment: New clues: when running the above query with `USING INDEX n:IpRangeBlock(start)` the execution time dropped to 11ms. I have no idea why it wouldn't use it by default :(

Comment: Oh, interesting!  Maybe drop by the Neo4j public Slack group ( http://neo4j.com/blog/public-neo4j-users-slack-group/ ).  Somebody might have a better answer in there

Comment: Meh, it seems that I was wrong, it's just that query with index on start tends to work better for some queries than others(depending on the IP i run the query for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I tried caching node references and performing the comparison on the app side. As you might expect - pulling that much of nodes takes time.

So I tried another approach - I examined our data set and it turned out that all ip ranges' `start` and `end` properties begin with the same first octet. I used those octets as grouping nodes to quickly narrow down subset of probable IP ranges. This worked well, as our dataset is actually well distributed across all ip ranges. now, instead of comparing 100k nodes' properties, each query has to do it 'only' for around 8-10k.

I know it's not perfect aproach but it worked for me. [There's neo4j article](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-cookbook-path-tree.html) I got this idea from.